# The actual use of ChainMapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have implemented ChainMapper in a program where there are two mappers and a reducer. Following is thecode in the way the ChainMapper has been implemented:

The code is designed to count the word occurences i.e. WordCount. 
1st Mapper  will read the file from input text file and split each text and store it in Context.
2nd Mapper will get 1stMapper's output and convert all the key Text data into Lower case key Text data.
Lower case key Text data will be stored into Context.
Reducer will get the value from 2ndMapper , Same key related values will go to one reducer task.
In Reducer we are simply doing word count operation with the given key.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

//implementing CHAIN MAPREDUCE without using custom format




//SPLIT MAPPER
class SplitMapper extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,IntWritable>
{
    StringTokenizer xs;
    private IntWritable dummyValue=new IntWritable(1);
    //private String content;
    private String tokens[];
    @Override
    public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
//      xs=new StringTokenizer(value.toString()," ");
//      while(xs.hasMoreTokens())
//      {
//          content=(String)xs.nextToken();
//      }
        tokens=value.toString().split(" ");
        for(String x:tokens)
        {
        context.write(new Text(x), dummyValue);
        }
    }   
}




//UPPER CASE MAPPER
class UpperCaseMapper extends Mapper<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>
{
    @Override
    public void map(Text key,IntWritable value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        String val=key.toString().toUpperCase();
        Text newKey=new Text(val);
        context.write(newKey, value);
    }
}



//ChainMapReducer
class ChainMapReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>
{
    private int sum=0;
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable>values,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        for(IntWritable value:values)
        {
            sum+=value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
public class FirstClass extends Configured implements Tool{
    static Configuration cf;
    public int run (String args[])throws IOException,InterruptedException,ClassNotFoundException{
        cf=new Configuration();

        //bypassing the GenericOptionsParser part and directly running into job declaration part
        Job j=Job.getInstance(cf);

        /**************CHAIN MAPPER AREA STARTS********************************/
        Configuration splitMapConfig=new Configuration(false);
        //below we add the 1st mapper class under ChainMapper Class
        ChainMapper.addMapper(j, SplitMapper.class, Object.class, Text.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, splitMapConfig);

        //configuration for second mapper
        Configuration upperCaseConfig=new Configuration(false);
        //below we add the 2nd mapper that is the lower case mapper to the Chain Mapper class
        ChainMapper.addMapper(j, UpperCaseMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, upperCaseConfig);
        /**************CHAIN MAPPER AREA FINISHES********************************/

        //now proceeding with the normal delivery
        j.setJarByClass(FirstClass.class);
        j.setCombinerClass(ChainMapReducer.class);
        j.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        j.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        Path p=new Path(args[1]);

        //set the input and output URI
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(j, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j, p);
        p.getFileSystem(cf).delete(p, true);
        return j.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        int res=ToolRunner.run(cf, new FirstClass(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

Now, I have a question. Can ChainMapper really lessen the burden of Multiple MR Jobs or anyone has the concept and the knowledge where the ChainMapper is actually put to use?

Thankyou :)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need two mappers here? Why not uppercase in the first mapper and avoid the huge overhead of the second mapper? That way you can get rid of needing to use `ChainMapper` too.

Comment: Yeah I could have done what you have  written in the comments above but I am practising ChainMapper and I just wrote the code to see whether I was able to code correctly(The program gave results as desired). I could have turned the word Keys into uppercase and have emitted them with '1' in a single mapper but I deliberately did so.

Comment: That is why I needed to know some use cases or examples where ChainMappers were actually needed so that I don't need to write such codes that can put so much overheads. I am quite aware of the overhead. Please sugges !

Comment: WordCount was just to test the ChainMapper

Comment: Reading up on `ChainMapper` then it appears that both mappers will run over the same data within the same task. However I still don't think this is at all good because you're still running more operations over the data than you need to. Maybe it can make your code cleaner in some circumstances, but cleanliness should almost always take a backseat to efficiency in MapReduce jobs. This is especially true with something like this where two methods could be used within a single mapper whilst maintaining the single responsibility principle. I wouldn't ever use it for Map->Map->Reduce operations.

Comment: So is it better to chain MR jobs rather Chaining mappers? I like the way you have explained it :)

Comment: Whenever I'm designing an MR pipeline, my number one thought is always to have it run in as few operations as possible. Each new mapper or reducer is a big overhead, so I will design the job to minimise the numbers that I need. Map->Reduce->Reduce is something that would be useful and is sadly missing from MapReduce (although possible in Tez), but I can't imagine ever wanting to do Map->Map->Reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Useful point indeed !